# Function differentiability proof

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

If a function is continuous and differentiable and the limit of its derivative exists, then it is differentiable at that point

Intuitively this is clear to me but I'm having trouble writing a proof.

Comment: hint: write down the limit definition of a derivative and use the mean value theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L = \lim_{x\to c^{+}} f'(x)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, $c < x < c + \delta$ implies $|f'(x) - L| < \epsilon$. If $c < x < c + \delta$, by the mean value theorem, $f(x) - f(c) = f'(u)(x - c)$ for some $u \in (c, x)$. Thus

$$|f(x) - f(c) - L(x - c)| = |f'(u)(x - c) - L(x - c)| = |f'(u) - L||x - c| < \varepsilon|x - c|.$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f$ is differentiable at $x = c$ with $f'(c) = L$.

Comment: okay I'll think about this some more. Thanks kobe